# program showing unwanted output

Tags: c

the problem statement on which i am working is as follows
One day Alice was experimenting with the numbers to make new algorithms. He introduce a new term Rsum. Rsum of any number is defined as number obtained by iterative summing of digits of the given number until single digit number is obtained.
For example:

```
    365 (3+6+5) = 14
     14 1+4 = 5
    Rsum(365)=5
```

Bob came in the room of Alice in his absence and change all the numbers on which Alice was experimenting by their corresponding factorials. For example Bob will change 3 with 6 (3!=321). Consider 0!=0.
When Alice start experimenting without knowing that the numbers are now changed. He got some ambiguous results and unable to find some pattern for his algorithm. So he wants your help. You are given a range [A,B] of actual numbers and your task is to find sum of all Rsum values in range [A,B] of new changed numbers.
So the input will consist of the range
and output should be Rsum

```
       for example:
       if we input 1,3 the output should be 9 that is 1!+2!+3! 
       which is 1+2+6=9
       or when the input is 3,4 the output should be 12 since, 6+(2+4)=12
```

this is my code

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        int main(){
   int num,range1,range2;
        printf("enter the range of the number:");
    int rsum=0,total=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&range1,&range2);

    for(int j=range1;j<=range2;j++)

    {  
        int sum=0;
        int factorial=1;
        
        for(int k=1;k<=j;k++)
        {
            factorial=factorial*k;
           
        }
        if (factorial >10 )
        {
            while(factorial>0)    
             {    
              int m=factorial%10;    
             sum=sum+m;    
              factorial=factorial/10;    
                } 
                rsum=rsum+sum;
        }
        else
        {
            rsum=rsum+factorial;
         
        }
    }

        printf("%d\n",rsum);
         }
```

the code is working fine for small numbers however in case of large range such as 41,49 the output is shown to be 0 can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Typical `int` in C can store values only upto 2,147,483,647 (`(1 << 31) - 1`). Factorial of 41 is too large compared to that. Using Python instead is an easy way to deal with large integers.

Comment: actually i have just started with coding and dont really know python so i am doing on c

Comment: i tried putting the range to be below 31 and there was a strange output. when i tried the range as 31,32 the output came out to be negative however with a range of 31,33 or 31,34 or so on the output seemed normal

Comment: Only factorials 12! and below fits in the limit 2,147,483,647.

Comment: yes you are right because the answer for the range 31 is too small i guess its just some trash value. which data types should i rather use?

Comment: You may have gotten used to pocket calculators being able to calculate `100!` and more. These use types similar to `double`. These give you a much bigger range, but limited precision.

Comment: the limit given to us for a and b is  of 10^6

Comment: You should use an array of integers to store each digits of factorial value.

Comment: thankyou for your help mike... but that would make my code exceed the runtime limit. out of 5 tests my code i passing in one and in 2 it is showing wrong output because of the 0 problem and in other two it is showing runtime exceded

Comment: yes, but sinse we are given in the problem to take 0! as 0 so we have to make the code according to that

Comment: This might help you: [Repeated summing until one digit is left.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789533/why-is-n-1-mod-91-equal-to-summing-all-digits-till-one-digit-is-left) Computing factorial modulo 9 is certainly doable. Just apply `%9` after each step and at the end remap `0->9` except the `0!` case.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the factorial and sum its digits at the same time. [Repeated summing of digits until one is left is equivalent to mod 9.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789533/why-is-n-1-mod-91-equal-to-summing-all-digits-till-one-digit-is-left). Modulo M gives the same result if applied at the end of the calculation or if applied at every step. Applying it after every step makes the result fit into `int` comfortably.

So:

```
int facsum(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0; /* as per instructions */
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i<=n; i++)
        res  = (res * n) % 9;
    if (res == 0) /* if the sum was 9, %9 would give 0, we want 9 */
        res = 9;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't the digitsum of 10! = 3628800 be 27 instead of 9? (And from k = 6 on, all digitsums of k! are evenly divisible by 9.)

Comment: @MOehm the question says "iterative summing of digits of the given number until single digit number is obtained" which I don't think supports a 27. But it's possible I got lost in it somewhere.

Comment: @MOehm ok, `if (n>=6) return 9;`  is a possible optimization if more speed is needed...

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's right there at the top. Sorry about that. I saw 3 + 6 + 5 = 14 and looked no further. In that case, the fact that all Rsums after 5 are 9 should come in handy. `:)`